# responsive split background colors in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if this is possible. I have a wrapper DIV that contains 2 columns which are responsive. I'm looking to fill the wrapper div with a split 2 color background i.e. one for each column so that as the layout scales down the background for each column is responsive.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `<div id="wrapper" class="row-fluid"><div class="span6" style="background-color:red"></div><div class="span6" style="background-color:blue"></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to have backgrounds for columns.so that they are confined to these columns alone.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4KLf/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="cOne"></div>
    <div class="cTwo"></div>    
</div>


#wrapper{
   display:block;  
}

.cOne{
   Height:100px;
   width:100px; 
   background-color:#333;   
   display:inline-block;
}
.cTwo{
   Height:100px;
   width:100px; 
   background-color:#444;  

   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to create a webpage which has 2 columns (assumption is 50-50) and both columns should have different colours(or images?). The responsiveness you expect, is unclear to me however (i.e., should the columns continously shrink or break into 2 full-width div's vertically the default behaviour of col-md-* with bootstrap - on smaller screens.)
Assuming shrinking behaiour, I have used col-xs-6 in the markup below.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="col-xs-6 background1">
         ............
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 background2">
         ............
     </div>
</div>

.background1{
    background-color:#eee;
}

.background2{
   background-color:#111;
}
```

What you mean by scaling down on backgrounds is also unclear 
:-\